# sails.js api blueprints are generating POST endpoints even for auto incremented id, how to avoid this?

Tags: sails.js, waterline

for example if I create a model called Job

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    id: {
      type: 'integer',
      autoIncrement: true,
      unique: true,
      primaryKey: true
    },

    name: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    }
}
```

the blueprint generates
POST method on **/job/:id**

But I don't want the users to be allowed to specify the ID by themselves. I want the ID to be auto-incremented by server. So the mentioned POST api endpoint should not be created at all. To create a new Job, there should only be POST endpoint **/job**

Is there an option for api blueprints to change this behavior?
Or is there any workaround other than disabling blueprints and defining the api endpoints manually?

Comment: Go to your config/blueprint.js and change "rest: true," line to rest: false. Or comment out this line. This will disable generating rest routes automatically and then you can create your own custom route. this can be a workaround

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The blueprint routes are a great shortcut to get things started, but ultimately I feel like you will probably want more custom behaviour than they offer in most cases.

To override the create access on just a single model, you can add a custom `create` method on that model's controller. So, in `/api/controllers/JobController.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    create: function(req, res) {
        var createParams = req.body;
        // do whatever you want with the passed in parameters here
        createParams.customCreate = true;
        delete createParams.id;

        Job.create(createParams).exec(function(err, createdJob) {
            if (err) {
                // handle the error
            } else {
                return res.send(createdJob);
            }
        });
    },
    // ...
};
```

If you want to manage blueprint routes for all models at once, see [here](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/blueprints) - you can turn blueprints off all together if that is preferred.

Comment: How can you do this in the actions2 format? Creating a job/create.js doesn't seem to work for me.